# Auto Execute Script

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to execute a script in Windows when a USB Device is plugged out or plugged in without any software. I need a script that would do that. I searched over internet but didn't find something helpful. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to a WMI event:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_LogicalDisk' AND TargetInstance.DriveType=2"

Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -SourceIdentifier RemovableDiskDetection -Action {

    $class = $eventArgs.NewEvent.__CLASS
    $device = $eventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.DeviceID

    switch($class)
    {
        __InstanceCreationEvent {
            Write-Host "Inserted, device id: $device"
        }

        __InstanceDeletionEvent {
            Write-Host "Removed, device id: $device"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran the entire script in the PowerShell. But it is not telling whether i have inserted my Mouse or Keyboard or have removed it.Please help

Comment: Because the script is targeting the Win32_LogicalDisk class. Change $query to  "SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity'" and $device to $eventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.Caption

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for [autorun.inf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/cc144200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

However, the functionality of automatically running scripts was disabled in Windows Vista and above to stop viruses spreading.

Comment: Basically I want to detect whether a Mouse and Keyboard is plugged in the computer with Windows. So I want to run a script when either the Mouse gets plugged out or gets plugged it which would check whether the computer has at least one mouse or not.

Comment: Assume that I have a script which can find usb devices and tell me whether there is mouse or keyboard connected to PC. But I want that script to run only when a mouse or a keyboard is plugged out or plugged in.

Comment: Again, C, C++ have events for this, use those events to launch your script.